# undefined variable inside view laravel

Tags: php, laravel, variables, view

so i'm trying to fetch data from my database into a datatable i got from getbootstrap

but i get the error:

Undefined variable: issue (View: C:\Users...\resources\views\dashboard.blade.php)

below ive listed the code where i use the variable: issue

**dashboard.blade.php**

```
<table id="datatable" class="table table-bordered table-striped table-dark">
<thead>
<tr>
    <th scope="col">#</th>
    <th scope="col">Issue</th>
    <th scope="col">begrootte tijd</th>
    <th scope="col">beschrijving</th>
    <th scope="col">Action</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tfoot>
<tr>
    <th scope="col">#</th>
    <th scope="col">Issue</th>
    <th scope="col">begrootte tijd</th>
    <th scope="col">beschrijving</th>
    <th scope="col">Action</th>
</tr>
</tfoot>
<tbody>
@foreach($issue as $issues)
    <tr>
        <th> {{ $issues->id }} </th>
        <th> {{ $issues->iname }} </th>
        <th> {{ $issues->begroting }} </th>
        <th> {{ $issues->description }} </th>
        <th>
            <a href="" class="btn btn-success"> START</a>
            <a href="" class="btn btn-danger"> STOP</a>

        </th>

    </tr>
@endforeach
</tbody>
```

**DashboardController.php**

```
    <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Dashboard;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;


class DashboardController extends Controller
{
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request,[
            'iname' => 'required',
            'begroting' => 'required',
            'description' => 'required',

        ]);

        $issue = new Issue;

        $issue->iname = $request->input('iname');
        $issue->begroting = $request->input('begroting');
        $issue->description = $request->input('description');

        $issue->save();

        return redirect('/issue')->with('success', 'Issue opgeslagen');



    }

}
```

the model
**dashboard.php**

```
    <?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Dashboard extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'issue';
}
```

Comment: Where you are sending `$issue` to view?

Comment: `/issue` to which action.

Comment: The code above doesn't send the Issue to the view. Is this the right code, or haven't you read the documentation? Also, `issue` is singular (enkelvoudig) and `issues` is plural (meervoud). The foreach loop should be `@foreach ($issues as $issue)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't send $issues to blade page, change your DashboardController like this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Dashboard;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;


class DashboardController extends Controller
{
      public function store(Request $request)
      {
           $this->validate($request,[
              'iname' => 'required',
              'begroting' => 'required',
              'description' => 'required',

           ]);

          $issue = new Issue;

          $issue->iname = $request->input('iname');
          $issue->begroting = $request->input('begroting');
          $issue->description = $request->input('description');

          $issue->save();

          $issues=Dashboard::all();
          return redirect('/issue')->with('success', 'Issue opgeslagen')
                                   ->with('issues',$issues);



     }

 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should pass the variable to the view.

Lets say you have a HomeController, and want to pass some variable to a view from the controller.

HomeController.php

```
public function show()
{
    $someVariable = "An Awesome Example";
    return view('example', [
        'someVariable' => $someVariable,
    ]);
}
```

example.blade.php

```
<b>{{ $someVariable }}</b>
```

You have to pass data to a view. Then inside your view you can show that data to the user. In my example I've created a array with the key **someVariable** and passed **$someVariable** to the value of that key.

Inside my view I can then use the key to show the value.